# How to select a declared variable from a script tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

Could you please help me?
I have the four below declared variable inside a script tag ( in a html page. They are radomly generated by folium in python.I would like to select the last one from another js file without success. I tried this

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var  name in this){
      if(Object.keys({name})[0].includes("layer"){
          alert (name)
      }
    }

};
```

Here are the declared variables inside the script tag in the html page

```
var circle_f3a483b3a7ba46748ac935d3995f4f6b = L.circle(
            [-16.0, 0.0]
        ).addTo(feature_group_1c28eff59e394734be54cf676a09eae1);
    

var circle_a01d1791063145b18b439bd7687bc97f = L.circle(
            [-11.3137, 11.3137],
        ).addTo(feature_group_1c28eff59e394734be54cf676a09eae1);
    

var layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb = {
            base_layers : {
            },
            overlays :  {
                "Roads" : geo_json_cae0ea33c63e4c438678d293e5c32c0d,
                "Intersections" : feature_group_1c28eff59e394734be54cf676a09eae1,
            },
        };
```

Comment: It looks like you're going too deep in your search. Name will be layer_control_... so you only need `if (name.includes("layer")` I would use `name.match(/layer_control_[a-f\d]+/)` for more precise selection.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I get a string type. How can I can get overlays key value?

Comment: All global variables are stored on window. `window[name]` or inside your function `this[name]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (name.includes("layer")) {
```

Would do the trick.

```js
var circle_f3a483b3a7ba46748ac935d3995f4f6b = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var circle_a01d1791063145b18b439bd7687bc97f = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb = {
  foo: "bar"
};

window.onload = function() {
  for (var name in this) {
    if (name.includes("layer")) {
      console.log(name , "=" , this[name])
      for(let key in this[name]) {
        console.log('key', key, 'value', this[name][key])
        
      }
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but I didn't work

Comment: but it does work, try the snippet. are these variables getting loaded after window.onload?

Comment: Please help me ! How can I get the dictionary value?

Comment: I updated my answer, please look. is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks, It gives me lots of thingds except the the dictionary values associated to the keys: "Roads" and "Intersections"